# How to monitored Network Printers and dedicated printers?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, monitoring

Im using a some network printers. there around 10 network printers around me. Some printers are shared through the Print Server and some printers are Dedicated. Im trying a solution for Monitor printing jobs of all these printers.

Currently Using the event viewer and the papercut app to monitor. So I can monitored the network printers. But Can I know about dedicated printers monitoring solution remotely. ?

Comment: If "dedicated printers" are printers that are usb connected to a PC, then the only way to monitor them is to install something on those pcs. You say you are using Papercut. It can do this for you by adding "secondary print servers". See http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/LocalPrinters

Comment: im just using papercut print logger tool. Its just a free loggin tool. It doesnt support any remote print monitoring.

Comment: So invest in the paid version, there is a free trial, but I don't know if that covers local printers. I do not know of any free software that will monitor local printers.

Comment: any script for access Remote Printer logs (Operational) ?

Comment: If you are using Papercut, use that to access the remote logs. Without something like Papercut, it's not possible.